# Import cannot be resolved in Eclipse from dependency in Play 2.0

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

I successfully added a dependency in Play 2.0 and was able to compile the project. When I try to run a simple test to render a PDF I get this error:

*The import com.itextpdf cannot be resolved*

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document; 
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException; 
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph; 
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

How do I clear this error with Play managing this dependency?

Comment: I'm having the same problem when adding Gson library. The library appears to have been properly added as a dependency but I cannot import it in code as it is not listed in "Referenced Libraries" under eclipse. Did u find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by running "play eclipse" on my project in command line and then Project-->Clean in Eclipse. Similarly for Intellij "play idea" and then File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and restart.

Comment: Shouldn't that be named "play eclipsify" ??

Comment: Eclipsify has changed to eclipse now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency is properly added, the jar should now be on the build path. Could you check if it actually is on your buildpath? Note that the /lib directory of your project is automatically included. You could try making a symlink in /lib to the jar